# Is there a concept of |x|<0?

Tags: order-theory

I'm just curious, did any of the famous mathematicians consider |x|<0?

Would the zero have to be then not the additive identity and what else would it be then? (assuming you could build a field with this)

Comment: What does $\vert \cdot \vert$ mean, for you?

Comment: "take the absolute value of $\cdot$ (which has to be greater or equal than the additive ID)"

Comment: Do you mean negative distance? Then search for [Krein spaces and relativity theory](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Indefinite_inner_product_space).

Comment: What does "absolute value" mean for you?

Comment: Are you talking about valuations?

Comment: In number theory, when one investigates, for example, numbers of the form $a+b\sqrt{3}$, where $a$ and $b$ are integers, it is useful to use the norm $a^2-3b^2$.

Comment: @Erick Wong: the distance between x and the additive element (normally 0)

Comment: What does "distance" mean to you?  You are speaking in generalities (additive identity) where there isn't a natural distance.

Comment: I do not think there is a formal use of this , but Some people use negative distance and create their OWN ideas. IT all depends on What that symbol means ! And What x is ! For instance : if x is a matrix , and the symbol the determinant. Or if x is a ring and we look for z norm ... your question is too open and vague. Hence the closure. Sorry :)