# Defining $|x|=-1$

Tags: definition, recreational-mathematics, absolute-value

### Q 1a

Is it possible to define a number $x$ such that $|x|=-1$, where $|\cdot|$ means absolute value, in the same manner that we define $i^2=-1$?

I have no idea if it makes sense, but then again, $\sqrt{-1}$ used to not be a thing either.

To be more explicit, I want as many properties to hold as possible, e.g. $|a|\times|b|=|a\times b|$ and $|a|=|-a|$, as some properties that seem to hold for all different types of numbers (or in some analogous way).

---

### Q 1b

If we let the solution to $|x|=-1$ be $x=z_1$, and we allow the multiplicativeness property,

$$|(z_1)^2|=1$$

Or, further,

$$|(z_1)^{2n}|=1\tag{$n\in\mathbb N$}$$

Note that this does not mean $z_1$ is any such real, complex, or any other type of number.  We used to think $|x|=1$ had two solutions, $x=1,-1$, but now we can give it the solution $x=e^{i\theta}$ for $\theta\in[0,2\pi)$.  Adding in the solution $(z_1)^{2n}$ is no problem as far as I can see.

However, there result in some problems I simply cannot quite see so clearly, for example,

$$|z_1+3|=?$$

There exists no such way to define such values at the moment.

Similarly, let $z_2$ be the number that satisfies the following:

$$|z_2|=z_1$$

As far as I see it, it is not possible to create $z_2$, given $z_1$ and $z_0\in\mathbb C$.

The following has a solution, in case you were wondering.

$$|\sqrt{z_1}|=i$$

so no, I did not forget to consider such cases.

But, more generally, I wish to define the following numbers in a recursive sort of way.

$$|z_{n+1}|=z_n$$

since, as far as I can tell, $z_{n+1}$ is not representable using $z_k$ for $k\le n$.  In this way, the nature of $z_n$ goes on forever, unlike $i$, which has the solution $\sqrt i=\frac1{\sqrt2}(1+i)$.

So, my second question is to ask if anyone can discern some properties about $z_n$, defining them as we did above?  And what is $|z_1+3|=?$

---

### Q 2a

This part is important, so I truly want you guys (and girls) to consider this:

> Can you construct a problem such that $|x|=-1$ will be required in a step as you solve the problem, but such that the final solution is a real/complex/anything already well known.  This is similar to *[Casus irreducibilis](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Casus_irreducibilis)*, which basically forced $i$ to exist by establishing its need to exist.

I am willing to give a large rep bounty for anyone able to create such a scenario/problem.

---

### Q 2b

And if it is truly impossible, why?  Why is it not possible to define some 'thing' the solution to the problem, keep a basic set of properties of the absolute value, and carry on?  What's so different between $|x|=-1$ and $x^2=-1$, for example?

---

### Thoughts to consider:

Now, [Lucian](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1345391/272831) has pointed out that there are plenty of things we do not yet understand, like $z_i\in\mathbb R^a$ for $a\in\mathbb Q_+^\star\setminus\mathbb N$.  There may very well exist such a number, but in a field we fail to understand so far.

Similarly, the triangle inequality clearly cannot coexist with such numbers as it is.  For the triangle inequality to exist, someone has to figure out how to make triangles with non-positive/real lengths.

As for the [properties/axioms of the norm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Norm_(mathematics)#Definition) I want:

$$p(v)=0\implies v=0$$

$$p(av)=|a|p(v)$$

Comment: Is it possible for the length of an object to be negative?

Comment: If anyone has some good tags for this question, that'd be nice.

Comment: hi, i asked the same a while ago: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1844930/is-there-a-concept-of-x0

Comment: @Math1000 I don't know, depends on the object.

Comment: @Math1000: is it possible for a squared number to be negative? (this is rhetoric question)

Comment: @LinAlg yes: $i^2=-1$

Comment: @saturatedexpo Well, hope this goes better than last time.

Comment: @SimpleArt i hope too. Just pointing out that you need to define some wierd stuff to actually make sense of $|x|=-1$ ;)

Comment: For real or complex x, it is not possible. If x is something else, then we have to define what $|x|$ is. Does that make sense?

Comment: This is an interesting question - I'm interested to see what the answer is.

Comment: @Srini defining "=" in another way might work too. But i don't think that's what OP wants.

Comment: @Srini, okay, then why can't we make the same rule as for imaginary numbers - $x=k$ ($k$ being like $i$) and there can be absolminary numbers (just made that up) like $5k+3$ for instance.

Comment: @Srini I want there to be a solution $x$ such that as many properties of normal absolute values hold e.g. $$|a||b|=|ab|,|a|=|-a|$$

Comment: For what it's worth, $|.|$ is sometimes used to denote the determinant of a matrix, and there certainly are matrices with negative determinant.

Comment: Say, does anyone think mathoverflow is a better place for this question?

Comment: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1852008/why-there-is-no-value-for-x-if-x-1

Comment: Hi Simple Art, I think you should define a new function similar to absolute value but it has these new characteristics , their curves will be different when visualizing in real and imaginary parts.

Comment: @Pentapolis Nah, I'd honestly rather try to tear down axioms first, as that'd be more fun ;)

Comment: John Baez discusses negative and complex absolute temperatures and also negative probabilities, but if I recall correctly, only as intermediate steps in formulae, where eventually real/positive/well-known values come out. Don't have the page-link at hand, google for baez and complex temperature or the like should suffice.

Comment: Try an object with a negative square root

Comment: (Hint: define it using sums instead of exponents)

Answer (score 8):

First of all, you can define $|\cdot|$ to mean whatever you want in any given context, as long as you're clear and upfront about it.

That being said, one usually wants $|\cdot|$ to be a *norm*, which means it fulfills a certain list of criteria. Among them is $|x|\geq 0$. If you break these rules, does your operation really deserve to be called "absolute value"? Does your operation deserve to be written using $|\cdot |$? Personally, I would say it doesn't, which means that using that symbol wouldn't be *wrong*, per se, but it would make it more difficult for your readers to understand what's going on, simply because of what they expect from that notation.

One notable exception, as pointed out in the comments, is the determinant of square matrices. And real / complex numbers are square matrices (of dimension $1\times1$), so in that context we really have $|-1|=-1$. But that's a different operation.

Comment: I guess, I do not understand: why cannot we just define it as $k$ (like we did $i$) or some equivalent and carry on?

Comment: @heather You mean "let's invent a new number $k$ such that $|k|=-1$, and see what happens"? You could do that. I don't know what happens. What would $|k+1|$ be, for instance?

Comment: $0$, maybe? I don't know. Are you saying that doesn't work?

Comment: @heather No, I'm saying I don't know what happens.

Comment: Do you think that any interesting results would come out of defining that, and all the rules surrounding it? Sorry for all the questions; I'm just curious.

Comment: @heather I don't think so, otherwise it probably would've been done already, and well known.

Comment: @heather Good thoughts, I tried putting some of that into my original question.

Answer (score 2):

The absolute value is quite a different thing than a square. A square simply comes from multiplication and nothing else. Especially, a square does not need an order on the underlying structure. However, the absolute value can only be defined after an order in defined by setting
$$
|x| = \begin{cases} x & x\geq 0\\ -x & x < 0\end{cases}.
$$
So, it is indeed *defined* to be non-negative. It is not that you may have some algebraic structure with an absolute value and then ask yourself "What if $|x|$ is negative?" in the same way you ask about squares… Put differently:

**You can't deduce form the field axioms that $x^2 = -1$ has no solutions, but you can deduce from the axioms of the ordering that $|x|=-1$ has no solutions.**

To answer the actual question: I haven't seen variant of absolute values (or norms, or metrics) to take negative values and doubt that such a thing has been studied.

Comment: $-x$ is not actually negative here.  And such definitions often times do not make sense, like if $x\in\mathbb C$, for example.

Comment: @SimpleArt Yes, what you are saying reflects that there is not ordering of the complex numbers… So if you ever want absolute values to be negative, you need to find a new meaning of "absolute value" and probably one not based on an ordering.

Comment: Well, to think back for a moment, how did we define $\sqrt{-1}$?  We never really gave it any new meaning, we just said "Hey, I'll call this number '$i$' and use all the same properties as before!"

Comment: @SimpleArt you are a mathimatical gangster hehe ;)

Comment: @SimpleArt ok, i deleted it, just saying i'm with you on defining new meanings to something and other's did too before you, as you pointed out yourself.

Comment: What I was trying to say in my answer is, that this does not work the same way as for square roots/squares. You can't deduce form the field axioms that $x^2 = -1$ has no solutions, but you can deduce from the axioms of the ordering that $|x|=-1$ has no solutions (I am going to add this to the answer…)

Comment: Hm, and if I decided I wanted to rework these axioms to include solutions to my problem?

Comment: Then @arthur's answer applies: Go ahead, but if you still call it absolute value, people may get confused.

Answer (score 0):

What about extending the real number absolute value to complex numbers in a different way?

For $z = re^{iθ}$, let $|z| = re^{2iθ}$

You still get that the "new" absolute value for all reals matches the regular one.

With this, we have
$|i| = 1\cdot e^{2i(π/2)} = e^{iπ} = -1$.

Answer (score 0):

When doing operations on complex or split-complex numbers, one can encounter a result which has negative modulus. In that case we consider it equal to a number with positive modulus but argument shifted by $2\pi$.
It is also of note that in split-complex numbers (tessarines) the modulus can be imaginary: $|a+bj|=\sqrt{a^2-b^2}$.
Thus, $|j|=i$.